# Correctness of the integral $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ when $f$ is not defined at $a$ and $b$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Knowing that the function

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ 
$$ is defined only for $-1 < x <1$, are the limits of integration below allowed?

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \,dx= \pi$$

PS: As stated above, I can calculate the result as $\pi$, I am just questioning the reasoning behind using $-1$ and $1$ as limits of integration when the function isn't defined at these points.

Comment: That is fine. Note that we aren't actually plugging in those values, but we are implicitly using a limiting procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral). Interpret it as follows:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} \,dx= \lim_{m \to -1^+} \lim_{n \to 1^-} \int_{m}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} \,dx = \lim_{m \to -1^+} \lim_{n \to 1^-}  \left[ \arcsin x \right]_{m}^n = \pi.$$

Comment: It is an improper integral in the Riemann sense.  It is just integrable in the Lebesgue sense.  (MBdr did not say what integral he wants ... but probably Riemann is the best guess.)